# Remove the table label within "longtblr"

Tags: tables, captions, labels, tabularray

I am trying to figure out how I can remove the table label (i.e. "Table 1.1") within the `longtblr` environment, that appears automatically even if I do not specify a caption.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[letter,margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec =  {t{8mm} t{10cm} t{5cm}},
  rowhead = 1,
  hlines,
  vlines,
  %row{even} = {gray9},
  row{1} = {olive9},
}
\textbf{Step} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Figure}\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669537/table-caption-remove-from-numbering

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624912/197451

Comment: Your example has several errors (starting with unknown option to `geometry`). Please correct all of them. However, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659110/277964).

Comment: @Luca did the answer below meet your requirement

Comment: @Luca please upvote and accept with a green tick check mark if the answer met your expectations

Answer (score 3):

Refer the answer here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624912/197451

[image]

Add the folllowing code to eliminate the caption `Table 1:`

`\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}`

[image]

**Complete MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
        \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
    \begin{longtblr}{
                                    rowhead = 1,
                                    colspec =  {t{8mm} t{10cm} t{5cm}},
                                    hlines,
                                    vlines,
            %row{even} = {gray9},
            row{1} = {olive9},
        }
        \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Figure}\\
                Step1   & Column2 & Column3         &   Column4       \\
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```